# How to check the less than condition in compiled queries of java?

Tags: java, mysql

In mysql we can check the less than condition by using '>' symbol but in XML files in java, how can I check that condition when we are writing query? Please suggest me. Its very helpful

Thanks,
Vara Kumar PJD

Comment: You can check the "less than" condition by using the "greater than" symbol? That's strange, I can't.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to have anything to do with MySQL or Java. Instead it's about XML only.

Answer (score 1):

How about escaping the character with

```
&gt;
```

?

Comment: just replace the > with &gt; and if you need a >= use &gt;=

Comment: or use &lt; for < if you want to check for the less condition

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the CDATA tag?

`<![CDATA[literals]]>`

`All text in an XML document will be parsed by the parser.

But text inside a CDATA section will be ignored by the parser.`

look at http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp